# NumberFormatException последнего элемента массива строк при приведении к массиву целых чисел

Tags: java

В файле *txt* лежат числа через пробел. *readFile(File file)* – возвращает корректный массив строк, в которых лежат числа. При попытке преобразовать массив строк к массиву целых числе вылетает `NumberFormatException`. Причем все элементы приводятся к инту нормально, за исключением последнего. 
Листинг:

```
public class GetDataFromFile extends GetData {

    public String getStandartPath() {
        return standartPath;
    }

    private String standartPath = "\\dataForExample\\example.txt";


    public String[] readFile(File file) throws IOException {

        FileReader fileReader = null;
        CharArrayWriter charArrayWriter = null;
        StringWriter stringWriter = null;
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try{
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            charArrayWriter = new CharArrayWriter();
            int count;

            while ((count=fileReader.read(buffer))!= -1){
                 charArrayWriter.append(new String(buffer));
            }

        }catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw  new IOException(""+ex);
        }
        finally {
         fileReader.close();
         charArrayWriter.close();
        }
        return charArrayWriter.toString().split(" ");
    }

    public static int[] stringArrayToIntArray(String[] strings){
        int[] ints = new int[strings.length];
        for (int i = 0; i<ints.length; i++){
            try {
                ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);// same result for "new Integer(str) and Integer.valueOf(str)
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new NumberFormatException("Error format in element "+ i + e);
            }
        }


        return ints;
    }
}
```

Собственно лог:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Error
>   format in element 23java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
>   "11
>   "
>         at com.company.Data.GetDataFromFile.stringArrayToIntArray(GetDataFromFile.java:50)
>         at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:25)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>         at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @Saidolim Djuraev С точки зрения семантики оформить лог в виде цитаты конечно правильнее, но преформат выглядит лучше

Comment: Покажите, что происходит перед вызовом `stringArrayToIntArray()`. Скорее всего нужно посмотреть на `com.company.Main.main()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В логе вот это место:

> For input string: "11          "

говорит, что парсер не в состоянии разобраться с пробелами.

Рекомендую воспользоваться методом `trim()` перед вызовом `parseInt()`.

Comment: Скорее, в конце строки лежит `\n`.

Comment: @VladD Там их мнооого

Comment: @tutankhamun, благодарю, добавил trim(), все работает.